# Create Custom SQL Order By Rules

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing, sql-order-by

I'm doing a basic select operation retrieving a varchar column in a MySQL database. The values stored in the column are "job numbers", and all have the form:

J##-####

Where the first two # signs indicate the last two digits of the year the job took place, and the last four represent the order in which the jobs were created.

Here's an example of what a job number might look like:

J11-0152 (The 152nd job created in 2011). The next would be J11-0153...

Assuming the records are stored in random order, is there away to retrieve records, sorted so that the most recent jobs show first?

e.g.
The records in the table are stored in this order:

```
 1. J09-1893
 2. J11-1323
 3. J08-0011
 4. J09-0234
 5. J10-1232
 6. J11-1111
```

Would be retrieved as:

```
 1. J11-1323
 2. J11-1111
 3. J10-1232
 4. J09-1893
 5. J09-0234
 6. J08-0011
```

I'm open to any solution that can be accomplished in MySQL. I'm using CakePHP as the app framework, so if anyone knows of a clever cake solution to the problem that could work too.

Comment: BTW, 'SELECT jobnumber ORDER BY jobnumber DESC' fails horribly

Comment: If the code has meaning it is better to store the parats in separate fields - can you change the schema

Comment: Only fails if you have data from pre-2000

Comment: By fails I mean it retrieves them an order different from the one I want

Comment: @Adam: For me and your example it retrieves in order that I want:)

Comment: It was because I had some dates pre-Y2K. Who would have though y2k would still be an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2-digit dates and job numbers should still sort correctly, even lexicographically.  But, if you had pre-2000 data involved, then you need this:

(sample table included - just ignore)

```
drop table if exists jobnumbers ;
create table jobnumbers (id int primary key, number varchar(10)); 
insert jobnumbers values
(  1, 'J09-1893'),
(  2, 'J11-1323'),
(  3, 'J08-0011'),
(  4, 'J09-0234'),
(  5, 'J10-1232'),
(  6, 'J11-1111'),
(  9, 'J99-1111');

select *
from jobnumbers
order by 
  case when number>'J5' then 1900 else 2000 end desc, number desc;
```

As for `indexing` (since you tagged it), two options:

1. you would have to split that into multiple columns to be able to index on year, then job number
2. Use 4-digit years.

Comment: Brilliant. It turns out that the numbers were being sorted properly, but the pre-2000 numbers were the problem

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_table_jobnumber ON table (jobnumber);
```

Then:

```
select jobnumber FROM table ORDER BY jobnumber DESC
```

"Fails horribly" means "is slow" to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUBSTRING() to get the part of the string you are interested in:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(myFieldName, from, to) AS myFieldAlias ORDER BY myFieldAlias DESC
```

So in your case it should be:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(job_number, 1, 3) as location, SUBSTRING(job_number, 5, 4) AS jobno ORDER BY location DESC, jobno DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your `jobnumber DESC` query again, or say why it fails. Maybe provide sample output that is inaccurate.